# Under what conditions does a series of matrices converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, functional-analysis

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{K\times K}$ be a $K\times K$ matrix over the real field, and some constant $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$.

Under what conditions does the following series

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \gamma^n A^n$

converge? In addition, what does it converge to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a geometric series. Let $B=\gamma A$, and use the "telescoping" formula

$$(I-B)(I+B+B^2+B^3+\cdots+B^m)=I-B^{m+1}.$$

Taking limits, if we assume that $\lim_{m\to\infty}B^m=0$, then

$$(I-B)(I+B+B^2+B^3+\cdots)=I-0=I$$

thus

$$I+B+B^2+B^3+\cdots=(I-B)^{-1}.$$

And if the sum converges at all, then the individual terms must approach $0$, so it's necessary that $\lim_{n\to\infty}B^n=0$.

This condition $B^n\to0$ is equivalent to having the [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Power_sequence) $\rho(B)<1$.

Comment: It looks like I didn't fully justify the convergence. If we assume that $B^n\to0$ and also that $I-B$ is invertible, then $I+B+\cdots+B^m=(I-B^{m+1})(I-B)^{-1}$, and taking the limit $m\to\infty$ proves that the sum converges. But if we don't _assume_ that $I-B$ is invertible, nor that the sum converges, but only that $B^n\to0$.... Am I missing something that I previously thought was obvious?